# How can I fix npm install "Cannot Find Module" error?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, package.json, npm-package

I have a react project and I'm getting the below error.

I have tried to delete the `node_modules` and `package.json` but I got permission not granted to delete. I have also tried `npm install`

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module './functions/valid'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\paul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js
- C:\Users\paul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js      
- C:\Users\paul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)     
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\paul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js:12:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)        
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {   
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\paul\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\paul\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\
```

Answer (score 5):

**Please follow the steps below:**

1. Delete the `node_module`s directory
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file
3. Run `npm cache clean --force`
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `npm start`

Comment: I had a similar issue and these steps fix my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thank u so much sir, i have deleted both directly from file manager because through vscode is was very slow ,after deleting i still the same error, module not found, 